# Optimal strategy of a probabilistic game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, game-theory

We have $n$ red balls and $n$ black balls in a box. We will take out a ball from the box one at a time and never put it back. Every time before we take out a ball from the box, you can decide whether to join the game or not. You will win the game if two balls of the same color are taken out consecutively after you join the game. What is your optimal strategy?

Comment: This is a nice question. It seems obvious one should be able to do much better than a half but even proving this doesn't seem obvious. It'll be interesting to know the answer.

Comment: It seems reasonable to wait until you know that there are significantly more balls of one color than the other. (the number of red balls - number of black balls) is a random walk of length 2n conditioned to return to the origin, with some transition probabilities that cause drift back to the origin. Suppose you could compute the distribution of the absolute value of the process - e.g. empirically. A strategy would be - make a reasonable tolerance for how close to the expected supremum you should wait to get before entering the game, and tune the tolerance to optimize your success probability.

Comment: What does optimal mean? Is winning once, losing twice better than not playing at all?

Comment: @Jeff - your question is valid, but I would argue (and this is just my opinion, obviously) that since the question did not mention anything like "(cost of) losing" or "cost of joining", therefore there is no losing and no cost of joining, and joining-but-not-winning is the same result as not-joining.  So you might as well always join.  In this interpretation, "winning once, 'losing' twice (i.e. joining-but-not-winning twice)" is just as good as "winning once, not-joining twice".

Comment: @antkam but exactly the same logic gets me “the op didn’t state a benefit to winning, therefore winning has no benefit so you might as well never join so you don’t lose”. Your logic includes an implicit assumed benefit to winning, but you’re not allowing the same implicit assumed cost to losing. You can do that if you like (it’s all assumptions after all), but it’s no more valid either way.

Comment: @Jeff - hahaha, ok I see your point.  I would still say "winning" implies a benefit, and "optimal" implies you wanna maximize benefit minus cost, and the lack of mention of losing or cost-of-joining implies those are zero.  But lets just agree on this: the question could certainly be written better to address these issues explicitly, instead of implicitly (IMHO) or not at all (in your opinion).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your strategy doesn't matter.  Consider the following alternative game: You can join whenever you want, but still draw all the balls out.  You win if the **final** two balls are the same color.  We observe:

1. If we join the alternative game at any point, the odds of winning this game are the same as if we had joined the real game (the final two balls have the same distribution as the next two balls, given what has been drawn so far.
2. If players A and B use the same decision rule when to join, but A joins the real game and B the alternative one, they have the same chance of winning (average the first observation over all times of joining).
3. Player B's chance of winning in the alternative game does not change at all based on his strategy when to join, so Player A's chance can't change either.

This is a variant on the "Next Card Red" game, which is described in Peter Winkler's "Games People Don't Play "

Comment: Woah! Totally counter intuitive to me, but makes sense (conditioned on the calculation in 1, which I checked in a few cases). Can you explain what the issue is with the strategy I guessed in my comment above? I think perhaps the issue is that my intuition was telling me that 1 was false, but it is true.

Comment: In “Next Card Red,” you have to join the game. “If [Victor] never interrupts, he’s automatically betting on the last card.” In the game described here, perhaps you can decide to never join the game. As a result, you have a strategy with positive expected outcome (assuming the payback for winning exceeds the wager for playing). Join the game only when you know that there are only two balls of the same color left in the box, which happens after $2n-2$ draws half of the time. You always win if you join.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt The probability of winning is $\frac{n-1}{2n-1}$.  This is slightly less than $50\%$, but it's also getting progressively worse the closer $n$ gets to $0$.  If you try and wait for a good starting point, what happens is that sometimes the "good" starting point will never happen, and you'll find yourself effectively playing the same game with a much smaller value of $n$, giving you a corresponding lower chance of winning.

Comment: @KevinP.Costello the point is that there appears to be an “opt-out” option in this scenario. If that’s the case, then “optimal” suddenly becomes undefined - is it “win the most money”, “win the most times”, “have the highest win rate” or what? If it’s that last one, then Steve’s strategy is 100% fool-proof assuming you can play as much as you want. All you have to do is wait for any game where all the balls remaining are the same, win, and then completely stop playing and you’ve got an optimal strategy. You’re making some assumptions in your answer because the situation isn’t fully explained.

Comment: (I think the following is a simple way to verify the first bullet: because the process is the same as assigning a order to the balls in the bin, so the process is unchanged if we multiply by another permutation. In particular, we can multiply by the permutation that interchanges the last two and the next two.)

Comment: The way the OP question is written, there is no losing, and there is no (mentioned) cost of joining.  If you don't join, you just don't win, which is the same result as if you join and then don't win.  I.e., since there is no cost to joining, you might as well just always join.  And because of _that_, this answer is completely correct.  You will win $(n-1)/(2n-1)$ of all games even if you play a long series and in some games you exercise the option to not join when you have no chance at winning.